# How do I find every certain string in a textfile with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to search and fetch every instanse of "`# XXX YYY`", another example would be "`# LOL foo`" or "# HAHALOL omgpls" (sry for my lack of imagination :P. If I can get the index in the text file for all hits on a search based on this It would be nice.

in a text file. I've tried a couple of times with regex but I cant seem to get it to work.

"#" is there always, then there is a space, then a string of unknown lenght but typical less then 5 chars. Then there is a space again then the same string with unknown lenght again.

Comment: So it's a `#` followed by max two words?

Comment: `^# .*? .*?$` isn't this all you need?

Comment: "*then the same string with unknown length*" - `XXX` and `YYY` are not the same. and `HAHALOL` and `omgpls` have different lengths. do they two strings have any similarities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this regular expresson

```
#\s\w+\s\w+
```

example

```
bool ok = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("# XXX YYY", @"#\s\w+\s\w+");

\s  --> space
\w  --> any word character
+   --> variable length
```

See here the [Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

EDIT:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("abcde # XXX YYY  abcde", @"#\s\w+\s\w+");
foreach(Match  m in matches)
{
    string value = m.Value;
    int indexOfInput = m.Index;
}
```

Comment: for the neewbie regex user, can you explain it as well? :)

Comment: "..., then there is a *space*, ..."

Comment: @juergen d:So i cant use it to find where in the textfile it hit(s)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about only a couple of words in the sentence or one, so you have to match the patters like

```
"#aaaa"
"#aa aa"
"#aa      aaaaa"
```

The correct regex has to be something like:

```
"#\w+ ?\s?\w+"
```

This matches:

```
\w+ - 1-N words
?\s - presence or absence of a space after first word
?\w+ - presence or absence of a second word with 1-N number of characters
```